# Is there any other option to run multiple node app on ec2 instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 3 file/app in node js in a folder

```
mis1.js running on port 3000
mis2.js running on port 3002
mis3.js running on port 3003
```

but when I run it on ec2 instance it show

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-7-220:~/microservice$ node mis2.js 
Server running at http://localhost:3002/
```

But on browser I am able to access only app with 3000

on my security group I have allowed all ports 3000-3010

Comment: You need to fix the listen address. "running at http://localhost" means it's not exposed externally. You need to change the listen address from "localhost" to "0.0.0.0" to listen on all network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

1. try running the three application with `sudo pm2 <entry file name>` example `sudo pm2 mis1.js`. when you use cmd/ctrl C it kills the application.
2. try opening the Ip to "anywhere" on your *aws* security-group